# Possible Jordan decompositions of stochastic matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form, stochastic-matrices

Which are the possible Jordan normal forms for the stochastic matrices? For some reason I got the idea that they always consist of trivial $1\times 1$ blocks even if eigenvalues of multiplicity $>1$. Is this right, and if so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. It is equivalent to assuming that the geometric and algebraic multiplicities of each eigenvalue for a stochastic matrix is equal. The counter example is:

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&\frac 13&\frac 23\\
\frac 23&0&\frac 13
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
where the Jordan form is:
$$
J=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0 &\frac 13& 1\\
0&0&\frac 13
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Beautiful counter example! +1.